# VisualForce not able to render select list

Tags: visualforce

I think I am missing something basic. I have two select lists: Region and District. Based on region selection, the district values should get updated.

Following is the code for VF:

```
<apex:page Controller="UserStatsController">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Goal Revision Dashboard" subtitle="District View"/>
<apex:pageBlock title="User Stats">
<apex:form >
 <apex:outputLabel value="Region" />
    <apex:selectList value="{!regn}" size="1" id="Region" required="true">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Valuesr}" />
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="districtSelect"/>
    </apex:SelectList>
<apex:outputPanel id="districtSelect">
    <apex:outputLabel value="District"/>
    <apex:selectList value="{!dist}" size="1" id="dist" required="true">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Values}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

And following is the controller

```
public with sharing class UserStatsController {

public string regn {get; set;}
public string dist {get; set;}    

public list <SelectOption> getValuesr()
{
    list <selectoption> lsreg = new List<selectoption> ();
    lsreg.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
    for (User_Stats__C Rgn : [SELECT Region__c FROM User_Stats__C where Region__c != null and Region__c != 0 and District__c != null and District__c != '0' limit 10])
    {
        lsreg.add(new selectoption(string.valueOf(Rgn.Region__c), string.valueOf(Rgn.Region__c)));
    }
    return lsreg;
}

public list <SelectOption> getValues()
{
    list <selectoption> ls = new List<selectoption> ();
    ls.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
    for (User_Stats__C dist : [SELECT District__c FROM User_Stats__C where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c != '' and Region__c != null and Region__c != 0 limit 10])
    {
        ls.add(new selectoption(dist.District__c, dist.District__c));
    }
    return ls;
}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from your query for dist, specifically the where clause:

```
Region__c =: integer.valueof(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('Regn'))
```

'Regn' is null when the page loads. Additionally, there appears to be a problem with your page DOM. The way it is structured, I don't think you'll get your getters and setters working in tandem they way you want. I've refactored your code a bit. The VF may not be entirely correct for your case since we're only seeing a snippet. But with this refactor, you can leverage the setter for regn properly and rerender the dist picklist using actionsupport. Also, I've added in a blank initial value for regn and dist so that the user is forced to make a selection, thus firing the onchange event.

VF

```
<apex:page Controller="UserStatsController">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Goal Revision Dashboard" subtitle="District View"/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="User Stats">
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Region" />
                    <apex:selectList value="{!regn}" size="1" id="region" required="true">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!valuesr}" />
                        <apex:actionSupport id="actionSupport" event="onchange" reRender="districtSelect"/>
                    </apex:SelectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="districtSelect">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="District"/>
                    <apex:selectList value="{!dist}" size="1" id="dist">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Values}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class UserStatsController {

    public string regn {get; set;}
    public string dist {get; set;}    

    public list <SelectOption> getValuesr()
    {
        list <selectoption> lsreg = new List<selectoption> ();
        lsreg.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
        Set<String> regionSet = new Set<String>();
        for (User_Stats__C Rgn : [SELECT Region__c FROM User_Stats__C where Region__c != null and Region__c != 0 and District__c != null and District__c != '0' limit 10])
        {
            String region = string.valueOf(Rgn.Region__c);
            if(!regionSet.contains(region)) lsreg.add(new selectoption(region, region));
            regionSet.add(region);
        }
        return lsreg;
    }

    public list <SelectOption> getValues()
    {
        list <selectoption> ls = new List<selectoption> ();
        ls.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
        Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
        Set<String> distSet = new Set<String>();
        for (User_Stats__C dist : [SELECT District__c FROM User_Stats__c where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c != null and Region__c != null and Region__c != 0 limit 10])
        {
            if(!distSet.contains(dist.District__c)) ls.add(new selectoption(dist.District__c, dist.District__c));
            distSet.add(dist.District__c);
        }
        return ls;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim! it solved most of the problem. The nullpointer error is gone! However, now when I select a value in Region, the district select list does not have any value to select and refers to only "None"

Comment: Can you post your full VF page? Maybe still a dom issue.

Comment: I have edited the main post to show the full VF page. Thanks.

Comment: Also the Region and District variables have repeating values. can that be a problem? How can I select only the distinct values there (probably add some attribute in controller)?

Comment: I just updated my VF as well based off of yours. You'll want to remove the required="true" from the district select list. That's preventing your regn value from getting set.

Comment: I also updated the controller to return a distinct set of values for region and district. Unfortunately since Region__c is a number field, you can't use GROUP BY in the SOQL query which would be ideal. Instead, I added in some logic to filter out duplicate values in a set. This could mean that not all regions or districts are returned, though, because of the limit on your query. You'll want to evaluate if you need a limit or not.

Comment: @Robin - If this answer worked for you, [you can accept it](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by checking the little checkmark near the down arrow and upvote it by checking the up arrow.  Check out the [about] page for more information on how the SFSE works.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: I accepted the answer. This is my first post so I am really new to this. I tried voting it up.but it says i dont have enough reputation point (minimum 15 required. :P) will do it soon, once I am eligible to.

Comment: @TimSmith I have another query. It would be great if you can help me with that. It is posted here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23514/visualforce-filter-values-from-multiple-objects

Answer (score 0):

Looks like dist.District__c is null.

You might want to add condition to the SOQL query:

```
and District__c != '' and District__c != null
```

Comment: Tried. Still the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Line 20 points to the NullPointerException being in your SOQL Query.  I've extracted it below:

```
SELECT District__c 
FROM User_Stats__C 
where Region__c =: integer.valueof(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('Regn')) 
and District__c != '' 
and Region__c != null 
and Region__c != 0 limit 10
```

It is likely that the `apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('Regn')` is returning `null`, meaning it is not found.  Then the `Integer.valueOf(null)` is throwing the exception.

If you want to use the selected value from your page then you can access it directly without using the `apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Regn')`.  You should change the variable name of your loop iteration variable, because it has the same name as the `Regn` String controller.

Then in your query:

```
for (User_Stats__C RegnUserStats : [
    SELECT District__c 
    FROM User_Stats__C 
    where Region__c = :Regn
    and District__c != '' 
    and Region__c != null 
    and Region__c != 0 limit 10
]) {
   // process it
}
```