# Visualforce: filter values from multiple objects

Tags: visualforce

I have 2 objects ObjectA and ObjectB.

Both objects have field called Sales_Rep__c.
The values of Sales_Rep__c in Object A are filter based on select list.

How can I use these filtered values of Sales_Rep__c from ObjectA to filter those records from ObjectB?

Here is the controller:

```
       public list<Schema.ObjectA__c> selectednames;
public list <Schema.ObjectA__c> getselectednames(){
        Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
             selectednames = [SELECT Sales_Rep__c, District__c, Region__c, Rental_Revenue_Actual__c FROM ObjectA__c where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist   limit 20];
                return selectednames;
       }

    public list<Schema.ObjectB__c> opps;
public list <Schema.ObjectB__c> getopps(){
             opps = [SELECT Sales_Rep__c, Rev_LY__c, Rev_CY__c, Rev_NY__c FROM ObjectB__c where Sales_Rep__c in: selectednames.User_Stats__C];
                return opps;
       }
```

Comment: I think this will be easier to answer if you include some of your VF/apex controller code. You can edit your question to update it.

Comment: Updated with Controller code.

Comment: Hi Robin. I'm afraid I'm not following what you're trying to do here or where your issue is, exactly. Are you saying that users select Sales_Rep__c from a select list and you need to use the rep they select to query a list of ObjectB__c?

Comment: Hi Tim. Not exactly. This is in continuation to the previous question. When a user selects region and district, the table on the VF page shows values for only those Sales Reps which follow the selection (which are present in ObjectA). Now in the same table on VF page, I also want some additional variables for these sales rep which are present in ObjectB. Let me know if this makes sense.